# Refactoring a Haskell function that uses the Reader monad

Tags: haskell, refactoring, monads, do-notation, reader-monad

I've got some code that looks sort of like this, ignoring all the code that isn't relevant to my question:

```hs
import qualified Control.Monad.Reader as Reader

data FooEnv = FooEnv { bar :: Int -> Int }
type FooReader = Reader.Reader FooEnv

foo :: Int -> FooReader String
foo i = Reader.liftM show $ bar' i
  where
    bar' i' = do
      bar'' <- Reader.asks bar
      return $ bar'' i'
```

Is there a way to refactor this? Specifically, the nested `bar'` function is bothering me most. Can this be condensed to one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do a little equational reasoning. First let's look at `bar'`. I'll write it in this form

```
asks bar >>= \z -> return (z i)
```

It turns out that `liftM` is defined to be `liftM f m = m >>= \a -> return (f a)` which fits the pattern above. So let's replace it with

```
liftM ($ i) (asks bar)
```

Then we have `foo` as being

```
liftM show (liftM ($ i) (asks bar))
```

Or, written out a bit particularly

```
liftM show . liftM ($ i) $ asks bar
```

If we know that `liftM` is `fmap` we might recognize the `Functor` law at play here

```
fmap show . fmap ($ i) $ asks bar -- equals
fmap (show . ($ i)) $ asks bar
```

I'm not personally a big fan of using `($ i)` as a function, so let's rewrite it as an explicit lambda

```
fmap (\f -> show (f i)) (asks bar)
```

Now, we could decide to eliminate the `asks` by using `bar` at the call site (i.e. use `bar` as a function of type `bar :: FooEnv -> Int -> Int`

```
fmap (\f -> show (bar f i)) ask
```

and as a final trick, we could use `flip` to go pointless in the `fmap`ped function and even return the use of `asks` (thanks Ørjan Johansen)

```
fmap (show . flip bar i) ask  -- or even
show . flip bar i <$> ask     -- or even
asks (show . flip bar i)
```

I'm not saying this is the most readable or wonderful way to perform this task, but you can see how we can just whittle down the pieces using equational reasoning.

Comment: Note that `asks f` is equivalent to `f <$> ask`, so dependent on your taste you could reintroduce it at the end: `asks $ show . flip bar i`

Comment: Thanks, @j-abrahamson! The detailed steps are very helpful. I should have been more specific, though, in that I do not want to inline `bar'` into `foo`. I will work to understand the steps you took, though, so that I can try myself to create a point-free version of `bar'`. I do prefer `asks` to `ask`, so thank you, as well, @Ørjan-johansen, for adding that final step.

Comment: I've figured it out: `bar' i' = asks $ flip bar i'` or `bar' = asks . flip bar`